# How to merge Worksheets from Multiple Workbooks into New WorkBook

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to merge data from multiple worksheets of multiple workbooks. 
For example, I have multiple Workbooks with multiple worksheets.

So consider I want to merge data from "Worksheet1" of "WorkBook1"  and data from "Worksheet2" of "Workbook2" and respectively into "NewWorkSheet" of New "WorkBook". I want to do this in a way that data is inserted into "NewWorkSheet" one below the other, like the first 20 rows from  "Worksheet1" then 
next 20 from "Worksheet2" and so on...

I could merge into a new one only from one worksheet only but not from others.

```
Workbook xlWorkbookDLA3 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dropBoxPath + "Week49DLA3.xlsm");
Worksheet worksheetDLA3 = xlWorkbookDLA3.Worksheets["Wed-A"];

Workbook xlWorkbookDLA4 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dropBoxPath + "Week49DLA4.xlsm");
Worksheet worksheetDLA4 = xlWorkbookDLA4.Worksheets["Thurs-A"];

Workbook destionationworkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dropBoxPath + "Test.xlsm");
Worksheet destworkSheet = destionationworkBook.Worksheets["Sheet2"];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range from, to;


from = worksheetDLA3.Range["B7:S7"].EntireColumn;
to = destworkSheet.Range["B7:S7"].EntireColumn;

from.Copy(to);


destionationworkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\ashish.mokadam\Desktop\DropBox\Test" + ".xlsm");
```

Comment: Since your code includes `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range`, I'm guessing this is for Excel, and that you are using the Interop library.  You may want to mention that (and tag your question that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each subsequent worksheet you wish to copy *from* (note, **NOT** for the 1st worksheet), insert the following code sample between "from.Copy(to);" and "destionationworkBook.SaveAs(...":

```
     var destination_start_row = destworkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;  // + 1 because Excel is 1-indexed
     var source_used_rows      = worksheetDLA4.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

     from = worksheetDLA4.Range["B1:S" + source_used_rows];
     to   = destworkSheet.Range["B" + destination_start_row + ":S" + destination_start_row + source_used_rows];
     from.Copy(to);
```

The problem is that you are trying to copy entire columns from the source worksheets to the destination worksheet, thus overwriting the values in the destination worksheet.  This code only copies a range of cells, not entire columns of data.

Also, you have a typo in your variable name "desti**o**nationworkBook".  It should be "destinationworkBook".

Comment: Hi Kyle..
is it possible to select specific rows and then copy it to new one ?

Comment: Sure, @ashish.  Instead of using `"B1:S" + source_used_rows`, replace `1` with the starting row number, and `source_used_rows` with the ending row number.

Comment: @ashish - Please be sure to mark an answer as "accepted" if it resolves your original question.

Comment: thanks Kyle.
there is a small issue , it includes empty rows too. can you please tell how to exclude empty rows while reading sheet.

Comment: @ashish: This is because there are rows that have been "touched" in the file at one point or another, even though there is no data in the cells.  You will likely need to exclude "empty" rows manually by investigating the value in each cell.